# Symfony unique entity ORM with multiple extended entities wrong alias

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities: BaseUser, User, Children. User and Children extends the main BaseUser entity. Basically when a parent registers to the webpage he can add multiple users(children). When the form is submitted "UniqueEntity" should check if email exists in the database. However now it return an error since the alias is incorrect.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.id AS id_2, t1.email AS email_3, t1.roles AS roles_4, t1.password AS password_5, t1.name AS name_6, t1.surname AS surname_7, t1.phone AS phone_8, t1.city AS city_9, t1.street AS street_10, t1.flat AS flat_11, t1.building AS building_12, t1.post_code AS post_code_13, t1.created_at AS created_at_14, t1.updated_at AS updated_at_15, t1.gym AS gym_16, t1.benefits AS benefits_17, t1.shirt_size AS shirt_size_18, t1.short_size AS short_size_19 FROM user t1 WHERE t0.email = ?' with params ["tevas8@enternet.lt"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.email' in 'where clause'
```

As you can see the alias is t1, but for some reason the WHERE clause is trying to access alias t0. I know that this is because of extending classes, but I have no idea how to fix this so that the alias would always match.

BaseUser.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BaseUserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class BaseUser implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private ?string $email;
```

User.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BaseUserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;
```

Children.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BaseUserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Children extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;
```

Comment: How are BaseUser, User and Children being differentiated? Sounds like BaseUser is a [MappedSuperClass](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping) or discriminator for User/Children, and that Children may be a [self-referencing OneToMany association](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing). Seems like doctrine is mapped for multiple entities on the same table and id. EG: `user.id = Children.id, User.id and BaseUser.id`.

Comment: You have not defined the Inheritance Mapping, looks like you want Single Table Inheritance https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance